# How can I convert HTML code into a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I am building an Angular 7 app.
In this app I let the users edit HTML that I then want to convert into JSON to store it in a way that make sense.

In short, I want to take any HTML code and process it into a JSON object. How can I do this?

Comment: You could maybe use something like [mckamey/jsonml](https://github.com/mckamey/jsonml) for the conversion between JSON and HTML/XML.

Comment: JSON and HTML are completely different structures. How do you even envision this working?  Can you given an example, a basic html and the expected output? What do you key by? tag, style/script/element? How do you preserve the order? Honestly it is much easier to just store the entire html as a string. That's how all the website builders work afaik

Comment: @sinanspd - Well, they're both capable of being tree structures, and JSON has arrays for order, so...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd parse the HTML into a DOM (you can do that client-side or server-side) and then serialize the aspects of the DOM that I cared about to an object, which I'd then use `JSON.stringify` on (if you really want JSON).

For instance:

```js
function converter(dom) {
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        return dom.nodeValue;
    }
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
        dom = dom.documentElement;
    }
    const obj = {};
    obj.nodeType = dom.nodeType;
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        obj.tagName = dom.tagName;
        obj.attributes = []; // Array.from(obj.attributes) gives us a lot of things we don't want
        for (let i = 0, len = dom.attributes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            const attr = dom.attributes[i];
            obj.attributes.push({name: attr.name, value: attr.value});
        }
        obj.children = [];
        for (let child = dom.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
            obj.children.push(converter(child));
        }
    } else {
        obj.nodeValue = dom.nodeValue;
    }
    return obj;
}
const json = JSON.stringify(converter(document.getElementById("example")), null, 4);
console.log(json);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" class="ex">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <!-- comment -->
  <span>
    Span 3
    <span>Inner span</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Obviously that's just a rough sketch, not a completely baked solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function converter(dom) {
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        return dom.nodeValue;
    }
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
        dom = dom.documentElement;
    }
    const obj = {};
    obj.nodeType = dom.nodeType;
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        obj.tagName = dom.tagName;
        obj.attributes = []; // Array.from(obj.attributes) gives us a lot of things we don't want
        for (let i = 0, len = dom.attributes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            const attr = dom.attributes[i];
            obj.attributes.push({name: attr.name, value: attr.value});
        }
        obj.children = [];
        for (let child = dom.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
            obj.children.push(converter(child));
        }
    } else {
        obj.nodeValue = dom.nodeValue;
    }
    return obj;
}
const json = JSON.stringify(converter(document.getElementById("example")), null, 4);
console.log(json);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" class="ex">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <!-- comment -->
  <span>
    Span 3
    <span>Inner span</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please always describe what you are doing in your answer. It should be updated or removed. Read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you provide more answers ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is only a copy of the already marked answer from T.J.Crowder, with a little change.
I have removed the empty strings and empty attributes and children node from the JSON result.
Code changes are commented within code.

```js
 

function converter(dom) {
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    //  add only if value is not empty
    if(dom.nodeValue && dom.nodeValue.trim() != '')
            return dom.nodeValue;
    }
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
        dom = dom.documentElement;
    }
    
    const obj = {};

    //  add only if value is not empty
    if(dom.nodeValue && dom.nodeValue.trim() != ''){
        obj.nodeType = dom.nodeType;
    }
    
    if (dom.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        obj.tagName = dom.tagName;
        
        obj.attributes = []; // Array.from(obj.attributes) gives us a lot of things we don't want
        for (let i = 0, len = dom.attributes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            const attr = dom.attributes[i];
            obj.attributes.push({name: attr.name, value: attr.value});
        }
    //  remove attributes if is empty
    if(obj.attributes.length == 0) delete obj.attributes;
        
        obj.children = [];
        for (let child = dom.firstChild;child;child = child.nextSibling) {
        //  add only if value is not NULL
        var childVal = converter(child);
        if(childVal)
           obj.children.push(childVal);
        }
        //  remove children if is empty
        if(obj.children.length == 0) delete obj.children;

    } else {
        //  add only if value is not empty
        if(dom.nodeValue && dom.nodeValue.trim() != '')
            obj.nodeValue = dom.nodeValue;
    }
    
    if(obj && Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype){
    //  do nothing  
    }else 
        return obj;
}

const json = JSON.stringify(converter(document.getElementById("example")), null, 4);
console.log(json);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" class="ex">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <!-- comment -->
  <span>
    Span 3
    <span>Inner span</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason, my change also removes the "NodeType" information - I will fix this later

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just add it to a json request to send it to an external server you could do something like this:

```
{
    "html": "<html>...</html>"
}
```

And send it to the server for further processing.